# Build GWT: GWT 2.6 / GXT2.3

Tags: gwt, extjs, gxt

i have some probleme to build my project; i have this error

```
gwt-compile:
        [java] Loading module 'cm.inet.Octopus.application.gwt.Octopus'
        [java]    Loading inherited module 'com.extjs.gxt.ui.GXT'
        [java]       Loading inherited module 'com.google.gwt.i18n.I18N'
        [java]          [ERROR] Element 'module' beginning on line 17 contains unexpected attribute 'type'
        [java]          [ERROR] Failure while parsing XML
        [java] com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.DefaultSchema.onUnexpectedAttribute(DefaultSchema.java:68)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.Schema.onUnexpectedAttribute(Schema.java:79)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.startElement(ReflectiveParser.java:211)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$ContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:314)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$100(ReflectiveParser.java:48)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:385)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:243)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefSchema$BodySchema.__inherits_begin(ModuleDefSchema.java:212)
        [java]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        [java]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.HandlerMethod.invokeBegin(HandlerMethod.java:223)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.startElement(ReflectiveParser.java:257)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:314)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$100(ReflectiveParser.java:48)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:385)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:243)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefSchema$BodySchema.__inherits_begin(ModuleDefSchema.java:212)
        [java]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        [java]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.HandlerMethod.invokeBegin(HandlerMethod.java:223)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.startElement(ReflectiveParser.java:257)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:314)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$100(ReflectiveParser.java:48)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:385)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:243)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader$1.load(ModuleDefLoader.java:155)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.doLoadModule(ModuleDefLoader.java:269)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromClassPath(ModuleDefLoader.java:127)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:156)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:124)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:88)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:82)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:131)
        [java]       [ERROR] Line 3: Unexpected exception while processing element 'inherits'
        [java] com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:338)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$100(ReflectiveParser.java:48)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:385)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:243)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefSchema$BodySchema.__inherits_begin(ModuleDefSchema.java:212)
        [java]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        [java]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.HandlerMethod.invokeBegin(HandlerMethod.java:223)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.startElement(ReflectiveParser.java:257)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:314)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$100(ReflectiveParser.java:48)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:385)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:243)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefSchema$BodySchema.__inherits_begin(ModuleDefSchema.java:212)
        [java]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        [java]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.HandlerMethod.invokeBegin(HandlerMethod.java:223)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.startElement(ReflectiveParser.java:257)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:314)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$100(ReflectiveParser.java:48)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:385)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:243)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader$1.load(ModuleDefLoader.java:155)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.doLoadModule(ModuleDefLoader.java:269)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromClassPath(ModuleDefLoader.java:127)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:156)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:124)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:88)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:82)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:131)
        [java]       [ERROR] Failure while parsing XML
        [java] com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.DefaultSchema.onHandlerException(DefaultSchema.java:56)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.Schema.onHandlerException(Schema.java:65)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.Schema.onHandlerException(Schema.java:65)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.HandlerMethod.invokeBegin(HandlerMethod.java:233)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.startElement(ReflectiveParser.java:257)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:314)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$100(ReflectiveParser.java:48)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:385)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:243)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefSchema$BodySchema.__inherits_begin(ModuleDefSchema.java:212)
        [java]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        [java]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.HandlerMethod.invokeBegin(HandlerMethod.java:223)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.startElement(ReflectiveParser.java:257)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:314)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$100(ReflectiveParser.java:48)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:385)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:243)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader$1.load(ModuleDefLoader.java:155)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.doLoadModule(ModuleDefLoader.java:269)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromClassPath(ModuleDefLoader.java:127)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:156)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:124)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:88)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:82)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:131)
        [java]    [ERROR] Line 3: Unexpected exception while processing element 'inherits'
        [java] com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:338)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$100(ReflectiveParser.java:48)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:385)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:243)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefSchema$BodySchema.__inherits_begin(ModuleDefSchema.java:212)
        [java]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        [java]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.HandlerMethod.invokeBegin(HandlerMethod.java:223)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.startElement(ReflectiveParser.java:257)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:314)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$100(ReflectiveParser.java:48)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:385)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:243)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader$1.load(ModuleDefLoader.java:155)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.doLoadModule(ModuleDefLoader.java:269)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromClassPath(ModuleDefLoader.java:127)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:156)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:124)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:88)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:82)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:131)
        [java]    [ERROR] Failure while parsing XML
        [java] com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.DefaultSchema.onHandlerException(DefaultSchema.java:56)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.Schema.onHandlerException(Schema.java:65)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.Schema.onHandlerException(Schema.java:65)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.HandlerMethod.invokeBegin(HandlerMethod.java:233)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.startElement(ReflectiveParser.java:257)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:314)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$100(ReflectiveParser.java:48)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:385)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:243)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader$1.load(ModuleDefLoader.java:155)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.doLoadModule(ModuleDefLoader.java:269)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromClassPath(ModuleDefLoader.java:127)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:156)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:124)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:88)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:82)
        [java]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:131)

BUILD FAILED
```

My ----.gwt.xml

```
 <module rename-to="Octopus">
    <!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff.                        -->
    <inherits name="com.extjs.gxt.ui.GXT" />
    <inherits name="com.extjs.gxt.themes.Themes" />
    <inherits name="com.extjs.gxt.charts.Chart" />
    <!-- Specify the app entry point class.  -->
    <entry-point class='cm.inet.Octopus.application.gwt.client.Octopus'/>
</module>
```

I want to know what wrong

Answer (score 5):

> ```
>    [java]       Loading inherited module 'com.google.gwt.i18n.I18N'
>    [java]          [ERROR] Element 'module' beginning on line 17 contains unexpected attribute 'type'
> ```

Looks like you're using gwt-user 2.6 with a gwt-dev from an earlier version. Make sure you use gwt-dev 2.6

(if you're using Maven or Gradle, or similar build tool with managed dependencies, it might be that GXT transitively depends on gwt-dev 2.5 and you don't force using 2.6; BTW I think GXT 2.3 doesn't support GWT 2.6, [you have to use GXT 3.1](http://www.sencha.com/blog/announcing-sencha-gxt-3.1/))

Comment: Correct, GXT 2.3.1 and earlier is limited to GWT 1.7-2.5.1, and GXT 3.0.x is only GWT 2.4.0-2.5.1. GXT 3.1 supports GWT 2.6.0-trunk (as of today), and there will be a GXT 2.3.1a release soon that adds support for GWT 2.6.

Comment: @ColinAlworth can you provide the source of your information?

Comment: Found it: [link](http://docs.sencha.com/gxt/3.1/getting_started/migration/Migration2and3.html)

Comment: Also note, if you are using something like IntelliJ it will sneak in say 2.7.0 without you noticing. Check the project settings and get rid of the errant setting.